# Which format is best to use for high quality online audio and video?

Tags: video, audio, format, media

I'm currently creating a site for a musician. They are wanting to include the best quality video and audio files possible.

After a bit of research I'm thinking:

FLAC is the best option for audio.

FLV or MPEG-4 is best for video.

Can anyone in the know confirm or correct this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd just like to add that "best quality" is not the only thing to look at. There are bandwidth requirements, ease of use (does it require a plugin, how many users can experience it without doing anything such as a download), etc. Keep in mind other factors that can influence your decision when picking a technology.

Comment: Are these going to be downloadable, or embedded into the page?

Comment: @Mr.K: I've got a very cool Hi-Fi setup (plain old stereo)... FLAC is indeed the name of the name of the game for people who want quality "dematerialized" music (as it's called) and on every single site providing dematerialized music targeted at audiophiles, you'll find lossless (typically FLAC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FLAC is lossless, so it should provide all of the quality you need.  File sizes will be larger than lossy formats (like .MP3).

I'd encode the video using [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264) (MPEG4 part 10) for video.  It's the best codec available for high quality video right now.

Comment: And it's not just that it's lossless: it is indeed lossless but in addition to it that can support format of higher quality than CDs. It can go up to 65Khz/32bits/8channels (as opposed to, say, 44Khz, 16bits/2channel for plain CDs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Flash with h.264 and AAC. It is the only solution with wide support. Everything else will cause technical problems for many users. There is no official and recognised standard about video or audio on the Internet. Every browser has its own.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, FLAC is the thing for the absolute best (lossless) audio.  However, there's something to be said for also offering high-quality (>300kbps) MP3 or Ogg Vorbis files; they'll be smaller and good enough for many users.

For video, h.264 seems to be the current winner, albeit with a complex legal landscape.